# How to select multiple columns while looping in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Please tell me how to do this i want to select multiple column while looping..

```
create or replace function insert_date_dimension("date" date)
 returns setof date as $$
declare
    dat date;
    start_date date;
    end_date date;
begin
    start_date := '2016/01/01';
    end_date := '2016/12/31';
    while start_date <= end_date loop
        --return next  start_date;
        select start_date,date_part('week',start_date),date_part('quarter',start_date),to_char(start_date, 'day'),to_char(start_date, 'month'),
        extract(year from current_date),extract(month from current_date);
        start_date:= start_date + interval  '1 day';
    end loop;
end;
```

$$ language plpgsql;

```
ERROR:  query "SELECT    start_date,date_part('week',start_date),date_part('quarter',start_date),to_char(start_date, 'day'),to_char(start_date, 'month'),
        extract(year from current_date),extract(month from current_date)" returned 7 columns
```

CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_date_dimension(date) line 11 at RETURN NEXT

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you would have to use `SELECT ... INTO ...` in a PL/pgSQL function. Besides, you forgot to `RETURN` something.

It is much easier to use `generate_series`; that way you probably don't even need to define a function, you could just use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`.

Here is the function as I would write it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_date_dimension(
   OUT "date" date,
   OUT week integer,
   OUT quarter integer,
   OUT dayname text,
   OUT monthname text,
   OUT year integer,
   OUT month integer
) RETURNS SETOF RECORD STABLE LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   dat date;
   start_date timestamp := '2016-01-01 00:00:00';
   end_date timestamp := '2016-12-31 00:00:00';
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY SELECT
         d::date,
         date_part('week', d)::integer,
         date_part('quarter', d)::integer,
         to_char(d, 'day'),
         to_char(d, 'month'),
         date_part('year', d)::integer,
         date_part('month', d)::integer
      FROM generate_series(start_date, end_date, '1 day') d(d);
END;$$;
```